# Camera stays blank on Oxygen4 (Android Nougat) with an OnePlus 3

Tags: java, android, camera

I've the problem that some users with an Oneplus3 and the most recent Oxygen 4 version (Android Nougat) don't see any camera preview image anymore (it stays blank/black). The UI elements are still visible.
They also said in previous versions of oxygen OS the app was working correctly. I found out, that other apps got the same behaviour and fixed it, recently (i.e. Google's Cardboard Camera). But I don't know how to fix it and don't have a test device like the OP3.

I'm using the min SDK version 14 and the Camera API v1 with a SurfaceView to show the camera preview. On my phone (LG G4 with Marshmallow) the app works as expected.

Is somebody of you familiar with that issue and know how to fix it? What else can I try to solve that problem? Can you reproduce that issue on others phones with Android N, too?

You can find the source here: https://github.com/kloener/visor-android 
For testing you can directly download it from Google Play (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.visorapp.visor) or on github-releases (https://github.com/kloener/visor-android/releases)

kind regards and thanks

Comment: Have you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

They need to give camera permission from application settings. I know they accept it while setting up app. But for Nougat user need to give an extra permission.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.The permissions are set correctly in the application settings. No other permission option is available. Any other idea?

Comment: Nougat have nothing to do with that. Marshmallow version already enforced run time permissions.